# How can I query who I am in AWS from the Java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, credentials

In particular, when using DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain in a test environment, it can be surprising which set of credentials the AWS SDK picks up. To this end, it would be helpful to find out, which user or role was used to make a request.

I tried with the following code:

```
    AmazonIdentityManagement amazonIdentityManagement = AmazonIdentityManagementClient
            .builder()
            .withRegion(REGION)
            .build();
        User user = amazonIdentityManagement.getUser().getUser();
        log.info("AWS self-check successful with user {}: {}", user.getUserName(), user.getArn());
```

This should work **if** the user has permissions to query IAM. On my test system I get:

```
com.amazonaws.services.identitymanagement.model.AmazonIdentityManagementException:
User: arn:aws:iam::999:user/test.developer is not authorized to perform: iam:GetUser on resource: arn:aws:iam::999:user/test.developer
(Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: xxx)
```

This gets close to what I want wrapped in an exception. Can I directly get the arn String?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/model/User.html#getArn--

Comment: @hjpotter92 Will this work with restrictive permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the ARN as long as the user has the permission to perform: iam:GetUser.
I'm testing similar thing so i can confirm that.